# predict() should display one value, but generates way too much values

Tags: r, predict

I have a dataset of the german soccer league, which shows every team of the league, the player value, goals and points. Freiburg soccer team has scored 19 goals with a value of 1.12. Now I want to predict out of the created linear model, how many goals the team of Freiburg could expect with a player value of 5. 
If I run the stated code line, the function shows me not one value, but 18 for each team. How can I change that, that I just get the value for the team of Freiburg? (Which should be the prediction 27.52 using the linear model.)

```
m3 <- lm(bundesliga$Goals ~ bundesliga$PlayerValue)
summary(m3)
nd <- data.frame(PlayerValue = 5) 
predict(m3, newdata = nd)
```

Dataset:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `predict(m3, nd)` without the `newdata =`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified your model in a way that R discourages.

The preferred way is:

```
m3 <- lm(Goals ~ PlayerValue, data=bundesliga)
```

Then the prediction works as expected using your command:

```
nd <- data.frame(PlayerValue = 5) 
predict(m3, newdata = nd)
#       1 
#27.52412
```

Although the help page of `lm` does say that the `data` argument is optional, specifying it in the model allows other functions, such as `predict`, to work. There is a note in the help page of `predict.lm`:

**Note**
Variables are first looked for in `newdata` and then searched for in the usual way (which will include the environment of the formula used in the fit). A warning will be given if the variables found are not of the same length as those in `newdata` if it was supplied.

This is why your original command doesn't work and you get the warning message:

```
predict(m3, newdata = nd)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
40.06574 28.31378 26.08416 25.45708 25.31773 25.22483 24.22614 23.55261 23.36681 
      10       11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18 
21.60169 20.51011 20.23140 20.25463 19.58110 19.48820 18.60564 18.60564 18.51274
#Warning message:
#'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 18 rows
```

The environment of your formula is not the bundesliga data frame, so R cannot find `PlayerValue`.

---

**Data**:

```
bundesliga <- structure(list(PlayerValue = c(10.4, 5.34, 4.38, 4.11, 4.05, 4.01, 
3.58, 3.29, 3.21, 2.45, 1.98, 1.86, 1.87, 1.58, 1.54, 1.16, 1.16, 1.12), 
Goals = c(34, 32, 34, 35, 32, 16, 26, 27, 23, 13, 10, 21, 22, 18, 24, 21, 12, 19)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```